# OpenCV: Why does Haar classifier only detect one face and one eye?

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier

I am an absolutely newcomer to OpenCV and Haar classifiers. I have copied the following code and it basically works fine, but it only returns one face and one eye. What about the second eye and another face?

```
    const char[] eyesCascadeFilename = "haarcascade_eye.xml";
    const char[] faceCascadeFilename = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
    const int HaarOptions = CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH;

    // prepare the image for fast processing
    Mat grayImage;
    cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayImage, grayImage);

    // detect the faces on the image
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, faces, 1.1, 2, HaarOptions, cv::Size(60, 60));

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
        // visualize the faces
        cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
        cv::Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
        cv::rectangle(colorImage, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8 ,0);
        // detect the eyes within the facial roi
        cv::Rect rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
        cv::Mat roi = grayImage(rect);
        std::vector<cv::Rect> eyes;
        // here's a problem ...:
        eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(roi, eyes, 1.1, 2, HaarOptions, cv::Size(30, 30));
        //eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(roi, eyes);
        for (int i = 0; i < eyes.size(); i++) {
            // visualize the eyes
            cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x + eyes[i].x + eyes[i].width, faces[i].y + eyes[i].y + eyes[i].height);
            cv::Point pt2(faces[i].x + eyes[i].x, faces[i].y + eyes[i].y);
            cv::rectangle(colorImage, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 210, 255, 0), 1, 8 ,0);
        }

    }
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Looking for the second eye rectangle ... : )]

Comment: did you try to remove the minimum size for detection?

Comment: yes i did. the yellow rectangle gets smaller, but it still detects only one or the other eye, not both simultaneously...

Comment: yes, eyes.size==1 when debugging...

Comment: what about using `detectMultiScale`?

Comment: what do you mean by this? is there any alternative?

Comment: does it never detect second eye or multiple faces or just not in that sample image?

Comment: no it does never detect both eyes simultaneously - either the left or the right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your code, in the inner `for` loop, you are actually making a new variable with the same name as the iteration variable of the outer `for` loop (`i`). *Since they are in different scopes this is allowed*, and the variable in the inner scope "owns" the name. You will not be able to access the outer-scoped `i` inside the inner scope.

The for loop declaration itself is part of the scope of the for loop, so counts as part of the inner-scope in the case of the second `i`.

In your case, this translates into the fact that you will only be able to draw one eye at a time for a given face, even if two were detected. You can't reach eye(2) for face(1). You are actually lucky your code didn't crash: this is only due to the fact that both your face and eye vector are of the same size (2).

In debug mode you got `eye.size == 1` probably just because at a particular moment the algorithm was only able to detect one eye. It is likely that at the next iteration `eye.size` would have been 2.

So, use, let's say, int j = 0 in your inner loop to iterate through the eye vector, and you'll be fine!

**END EDIT**

This is my own (working) version of this algorithm:

```
#include "FaceDetectionHaar.h"


FaceDetectionHaar::FaceDetectionHaar()
{
    face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";

    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n");};
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n");};
}

void FaceDetectionHaar::execute(IplImage in)
{
    Mat imgMat(&in);

    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor( imgMat, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
        ellipse( imgMat, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

        Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
        std::vector<Rect> eyes;

        //-- In each face, detect eyes
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

        for( int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
        {
            Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
            int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[i].height)*0.25 );
            circle( imgMat, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
    in = imgMat;
}
```

The code is way simpler than yours for the ROI part. And maybe the use of the Haar option `CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE` instead of `CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH` will help.

This code is for the most part a copy of the one given on the [OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html). You should try the Haar Cascades xml files they provide too, both for faces and eyes.

Comment: didnt know about the flags. CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH will probably be the problem!!!

Comment: I think so too. Worth a try anyway! :)

Comment: I now have set the Haar options to 0 and -1, but still the same problem. I will try your algorithm... but this is a really strange problem.

Comment: okay I now tried it with your algorithm and it works fine : ) I am wondering where the difference is - I can't spot it... Tried mine with ( 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE ) for the flag in detectMultiScale, but without success. Btw. your algorithm is somehow half that fast that mine, don't ask me why...

Comment: @CTZStef: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I didn't know that C++ handles the scope this way. I'm always glad to learn something new : )

Answer (score 1):

Okay I now solved the problem with my algorithm too... Very akward, I used for the eyes loop the same iteration variable "i" like for the outer loop to iterate through the faces... :-/ Strange that the compiler didn't gave me an error that variable "i" is already defined...!

Here's the working code:

```
    const char[] eyesCascadeFilename = "haarcascade_eye.xml";
    const char[] faceCascadeFilename = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
    const int HaarOptions = CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH;

    // prepare the image for fast processing
    Mat grayImage;
    cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayImage, grayImage);

    // detect the faces on the image
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayImage, faces, 1.1, 2, HaarOptions, cv::Size(60, 60));

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
        // visualize the faces
        cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
        cv::Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
        cv::rectangle(colorImage, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8 ,0);
        // detect the eyes within the facial roi
        cv::Rect rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
        cv::Mat roi = grayImage(rect);
        std::vector<cv::Rect> eyes;
        // here's a problem ...:
        eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(roi, eyes, 1.1, 2, HaarOptions, cv::Size(30, 30));
        //eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(roi, eyes);
        for (int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++) {
            // visualize the eyes
            cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height);
            cv::Point pt2(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y);
            cv::rectangle(colorImage, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 210, 255, 0), 1, 8 ,0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ah! Yes! Of course! Now I see it! Have a look to my edited answer above...!